# MongoDB aggregate queries, find which failed

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is there a way to find which specific queries caused the aggregate to not return anything?
e.g:

```
aggregation = [
        {'$geoNear': SON([('near', self.center), ('distanceField', "distance"), ('maxDistance', self.radius), ('spherical', True)])},
        {'$match': {'$expr': {'$gt': [{'$size': {'$setIntersection': [types,"$types"]}}, 0]}}},            
        {'$match': {'_id': {'$nin': destinationsSeen}}},
        {'$match': {'types': {'$nin': typesSeen}}}
```

Is it possible to find if the the "geoNear" query could not find anything even if the other "match" queries did? 
I have looked through the documentation but can't seem to find anything on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use iterative testing.

That is, run the aggregation with only the first stage to see what is returned.  If it is not empty, run it again with just the first 2 stages.

Repeat until the result set is empty, the last stage that was added is the one causing there to be no matches.

You can then examine the output from the previous test to see *why* there was nothing matched.